# create a 3D Cube in a c# metro app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I want do develope a 3D Cube in a metro app using c#. In a WPF Application I used a Viewport3DContral in a XAML-component. But this don´t exist in .Net Framework for windows 8. Have anybody expirience to develope a 3D Cube in a c# metro app. There exist DirectX for c++ applications. Is it possible to include a Direct3D App in a existing c# metro app? Maybe it exist a 3D-Engine for c# metro apps?

Comment: you can create for example a C++ WinRT component and use it in your C# app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SharpDx](http://sharpdx.org/), it is a managed wrapper for DirectX.